# OpenCV merge two masks

Tags: android, opencv, colors, merge, mask

I would like to merge by "setTo()" two masks together. But I get an error i don't know why.

**_ First mask is input video frame (RGBA actually black and white cause of inRange)
_** Second mask is a simple yellow mask(8UC4 i think it must be)

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 0);
        Core.inRange(rgba,  new Scalar(10,100,100), new Scalar(30,255,255), rgba);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
        Mat yellow_mask = new Mat(cols, rows, CvType.CV_8UC4, new Scalar(255,255,0, 100));
        rgba.setTo(yellow_mask, rgba);
```

My goal is to make white inRange into Yellow.

**EDIT 1**

```
// DETECT YELLOW 
        Mat hsv = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

        Mat mask = new Mat();
        Core.inRange(hsv,  new Scalar(10,100,100), new Scalar(30,255,255), mask);

        rgba.setTo(new Scalar(255,255,0, 100), mask);
```

Crash detected every 15 secondes after the launch :/

Answer (score 1):

- first of all, a *mask* is a 8bit, one channel binary image.
- then, you can *never* retrieve the colors back from a grayscale or binary image (think of it ..)
- recycling your rgba Mat for each and every step of it - bad idea.

so try like this:

```
    Mat hsv = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2HSV);

    Mat mask = new Mat();
    Core.inRange(hsv,  new Scalar(10,100,100), new Scalar(30,255,255), mask);

    rgba.setTo(new Scalar(255,255,0, 100), mask);
```

Comment: I tested your code, it'es cleaner than me thanks !
But (i return rgba right ?), i still got an error :/

Comment: Okay it's fine, you just forget the replace rgba now it's working as well. I just have to flash them now

Comment: Don't worry, it works. I just released masks used :)